# Assigning to reference variable

Tags: c#, reference

Using C# 7.3.
In this code:

```
int a = 0;
ref int b = ref a;
...
...
b = ref a;
b = a;
```

- Are the two last assignments exactly equivalent (assigning a reference), in spite one assigns the value of a while the other assigns the reference of a? If so why?
- If not, why is it allowed to assign a value to a `ref` variable (last line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're not the same; it is clearer if you use more values; here `a` is just a dummy to initialize - the important bit is how the usage with `c` and `d` work differently; with `b = ref c;` we *update the reference* that `b` points to to `c`, so if we look at `c` afterwards: it is different; with `b = d;` we update the *value of the thing that `b` points at*, so it behaves very differently - `b` still points at the location of variable `c`.

```
    int a = 0;
    ref int b = ref a;
    int c = 1, d = 2;


    b = ref c;
    b = 42;
    System.Console.WriteLine(c); // 42
    System.Console.WriteLine(d); // 2

    b = d;
    b = 64;
    System.Console.WriteLine(c); // 64
    System.Console.WriteLine(d); // 2
```

If we compare in terms of pointers, and say that `b` was an `int*` pointer:

- `b = ref a;` is `b = &a`
- `b = a` is `*b = a`

Comment: Yep, I realize my question was based on a misunderstanding, as both variables in my question continue to refer to the same actual storage. Assigning the value of `a` to `b` just tries to update the referenced storage with its own value, which does nothing.